# Issue with date format conversion Python to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with the 'date' column in the below format (MMDDYYYY).

```
04161957  
01021965  
02081943
```

I need it to be:

```
1957-04-16  
1965-01-02  
1943-02-08
```

I've tried:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m%d%Y')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df.to_csv(output_file,index=False)
```

For some reason, this creates:

```
4/16/1957  
1/2/1965  
2/8/1943
```

When I remove the hyphen in the date format like such:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

It creates:

```
19570416  
19650102  
19430208
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are probably opening the file in a spreadsheet app that has its own default date format. Try to open the file in a **raw** text editor.

Comment: Right.  This is an Excel problem.  Your file is being created exactly as you want, but your default Excel date format is mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: right click and open as txt